# Global Payments Hosted Fields won't display on Blazor Web Assembly app unless a page Refresh

Tags: global-payments-api

I am required to use the Hosted Fields solution from Global Payments.  I include the javascript file in index.html and add the div's to the razor page.  I make a call to JS Interop from the OnAfterRenderAsync in the razor page which configures and calls the cardform creation.  However, the Hosted Fields don't display unless I do a Refresh or back button then forward or if I use developer tools to inspect, then the fields display.

I tried reloading the window, I'll take a flicker at this point.  I have tried moving it to a separate component and setting a dummy field to force a state change.  I have tried reload, refresh, reset the entire form, nothing.  It only displays if I press F5 or go back a page and go into the page again or if I go to Developer Tools and Inspect.  I expected to see the Hosted Fields.

What is strange is that I use this same Razor Class Library in .Net Maui Blazor Hybrid and it works fine, but if I use in the Blazor Web Assembly it doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

[Blazor WASM not load LocalStorage or IndexedDB from IFrame #44587](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/44587#issuecomment-1287104756)